# Is there a way to change the path that my files must be saved other than /var/www/html?

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I installed `apache2`, `mariadb` and `phpmyadmin`. I can find my database through (ip) `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin` but i want to save my projects somewhere other than `/var/www/html`.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use symlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course:
check [ServerRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot) in your apache config.

Here are few [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html):

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Running `apachectl -s` i found the following                                                                                     ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"                                                                                                        Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"                                                                                       So i should manipulate the conf file in /etc/apache2 and change /var/www/html to lets say /home/username/Desktop/filename ?

Comment: yes, or create a separate vhosts file, with a ServerName and DocumentRoot .. `/var/www/html` is just the default , when there's no other config.. There are plenty of apache vhost examples online.

Comment: yes i read some but i was not sure if i will mess up phpmyadmin's path by creating virtual host

Comment: The best way to learn, is to mess it up, then fix it ;)

Comment: haha you are right! (Been there). Thanks a lot for your help! I finally managed to do it the way i wanted! cheers